# How to apply Gaussian box filter to an integral image?

Tags: computer-vision, filtering

I'd explored some papers about integral image and how to use it. It's easy to calculate sum of pixel intensities, or mean intensity within a shape, also easy to make a convolve with Haar filter. But will it give speed up in comparison with the original grayscale image when using Gauss box filter? How to apply this box for integral image for example?

```
0 1 0
1 3 1
0 1 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each pixel, the output of a box filter is the average of the image part enclosed in the box centered on the said pixel. So, basically, to apply box filtering, just use take teh mean intensity inside the rectangle.

Gaussian blur can't be applied this way because it applies some non-uniform weights to the pixels in the box.

For the performance:

- naive convolution has some O(N x M^2) complexity, where N is the number of pixels in the image and M^2 is the number of pixels in the (square) blur kernel and does M^2 multiplications-and-adds per output pixel;
- separable Gaussian convolution turns this complexity into O(N) (just2 passes over the pixels) and requires 2M multiplication-and-adds per output pixel;
- forgetting the integral image computation, box filtering with integral images has again O(N) complexity, but requires now only 3 additions / subtractions per output pixel.

As you see, filtering with integral images is very interesting when the size of the blur kernel is large: its runtime does not depend at all on this parameter. What you pay for that is some blur kernel that only approximates Gaussian blur.

Comment: What should be filter size to approximate gaussian blur with standard deviation s using integral image?